Cant ping ipv6 address
Can't use ping command or other commands, programs to connect to ipv6 addresses
└─$ ping6 2607:f8b0:4005:803::200e

ping6: connect: Network is unreachable

└─$ traceroute6 2001:4860:4860::8888

traceroute to 2001:4860:4860::8888 (2001:4860:4860::8888), 30 hops max, 80 byte packets
connect: Network is unreachable



Does your system have a global IPv6 address? 2) Does your system have an IPv6 default gateway set (a ::/0 route)?


Does $ ip a include ipv6 adresses, if not, it might well be turned off in e.g. Settings (Ubuntu). But: Network is unreachable is what you see if a network cable isn't connected, or routing is "bad".
